# How does Violent Awakening work with Flurry of Blows and Furious Assault?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, monk

The feat *Violent Awakening* goes off when both *Flurry of Blows* and *Furious Assault* (the Half-orc Racial) are triggered. Both are triggered when I hit an enemy. This feat adds extra damage to my Flurry of Blows monk ability which is an at-will. Furious Assault however, is an encounter power.

Does this mean that as long as I have the Furious Assault encounter power available, every turn I hit an enemy I can add the Violent Awakening damage to Flurry of Blows? Or can I only use this added damage once?

Answer (score 8):

No.

For the power to be considered *triggered* you have to actually choose to use the power.

This is a once/encounter move, unless you have a way to recharge your Furious Assault power (there are a number of power recovery options, but that's out of scope for this particular question).

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot keep using Violent Awakening as long as you have Furious Assault available.

Violent Awakening only works when Furious Assault and your Flurry of Blows are both triggered on the same hit. In order for that to happen you have to declare the use of Furious Assault to empower a Flurry of Blows attack, at which point you can add the extra Strength Mod damage. Since Furious Assault is an Encounter power you can only use this once in a fight.